# Create C++ discrete distribution from list

Tags: c++, std

I am trying to create a std::discrete_distribution:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution

All the examples I have seen define it like in the link above `std::discrete_distribution<> d({40, 10, 10, 40});`

But instead of `{40, 10, 10, 40}` I would like to do this programmatically, rather than hardcoded.

Comment: [Constructor 2 takes iterators.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution)

Comment: What do you mean by "programmatically"? Please ask a precise question, using objective terms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::discrete_distribution` has a [constructor overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution) that takes iterators, so modifying cppreference's example to use a `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    std::vector<int> list{40, 10, 10, 40};
    std::discrete_distribution<> d(list.begin(), list.end());
    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++m[d(gen)];
    }
    for(auto p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    }
}
```

The vector can be loaded however you like. Here I used the same initializer list to generate similar results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the other constructor defined for discrete_distribution which takes a pair of iterators. I just modified the code from en.cppreference.com such that `discrete_distribution` takes pair of iterators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::array<int, 4> a{40, 10, 10, 40};
    std::discrete_distribution<> d(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++m[d(gen)];
    }
    for(auto p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    }
}
```